# sql query get only 1 value of many in a joined table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, join

This is about a Wordpress website.

There are 2 tables. 1 called `wp_users` and 1 called `wp_usermeta`.
The 2 tables are linked by `wp_users.id = wp_usermeta.user_id`.
Usermeta has a column named `meta_key` and `meta_value`. 1 user has multiple `meta_key`'s, but each `meta_key` also has a `meta_value`.

What I would like to have is as following,

I'd like to select the `ID`, `user_login` & `user_email` from `wp_users` and `meta_value` from `wp_usermeta` where `meta_key` = 'foobar' . However, the query needs to be made in such a way that if someone uses the search, it will still find the same but only if `user_login`, `user_email` or `meta_value` contains the searched string.

Here is what I currently have. I have tried joining the tables, but I'm quite unsure of how to do this exactly.

```
public function get_users($get_from, $per_page, $search = null) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql =      "SELECT ID, user_login username, user_email FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users";

    if(isset($search)) {
        $sql .= " WHERE user_login LIKE '%" . esc_sql($wpdb->esc_like($search)) . "%'";
        $sql .= " OR user_email LIKE '%" . esc_sql($wpdb->esc_like($search)) . "%'";
    }

    if(!empty($_REQUEST['orderby'])){ 
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . esc_sql($_REQUEST['orderby']);
        $sql .= !empty($_REQUEST['order']) ? ' ' . esc_sql($_REQUEST['order']) : ' ASC';
    }

    $sql .= " LIMIT $get_from , $per_page";
    echo $sql;

    $result = $wpdb-> get_results($sql, 'ARRAY_A');
    $this->total_users = $wpdb->num_rows;

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: `wp_usermeta` works like `wp_postmeta`. Try looking for advice, here on SO or elsewhere, for querying that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather use union, it is faster in my experience than a series of or conditions.

```sql
SELECT ID, user_login username, user_email
FROM users
WHERE user_login LIKE '%...%'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT ID, user_login username, user_email
FROM users
WHERE user_email LIKE '%...%'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT ID, user_login username, user_email
FROM users
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON users.id=wp_usermeta.user_id
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='foobar' and wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%...%'
```

Alternatively, you can concatenate the 3 fields into one and to the like on the concatenated string:

```sql
SELECT ID, user_login username, user_email
FROM users
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ON users.id=wp_usermeta.user_id
AND wp_usermeta.meta_key='foobar' 
WHERE concat_ws(',',user_login, user_email, coalesce(wp_usermeta.meta_value,'') LIKE '%...%'
```

Comment: In the union example, you're not fetching the meta value, you're only using it to search through. This would work if I only needed ID, user_login and user_email but I also want the meta_value.  
As for the concat option, it's giving me an error on limit? Which I had not even had active (Purely copied and slightly edited names and pasted in phpmyadmin)

Comment: 1) You can join the meta table to all the queries in the union. I used **your** query as a starting point. 2) Are you asking me if your query returns an error or stating it? If you are stating it, then pls provide exact error message and the exact query you tried to run.

Comment: 1) Oh ofc. I'll try that out! 2) I was stating, appologies. `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 6` but the query is 5 lines and has no limit.

Comment: 2) Are you trying to execute the query from phpmyadmin? Because phpmyadmin always appends a limit clause to the select queries, but sometimes appends it to the wrong place. It is a known issue. Actually, most GUI based clients do this silently.

Comment: 1) I have joined the table and I'm getting the information I want, I'll be using this, thanks a lot! 2) Yeah, I copied it and pasted it in phpmyadmin.